# variable in POST - php

Tags: php, post

i am really stuck in this silly problem. i have a dynamic form variable `test_nr`, that `nr` is dynamic. then i wanted to catch that in `POST` in this way:

```
$test = $_POST['test_'.$nr.''];
```

but this isnot working somehow, i am wondering where the typo is. for me it is grammatically right. this problem is causing this while loop run forever:

```
$in=1;
while($in<5){
    $time_.$in=$_POST['zeit_'. $in .''];
    $erfahrung_. $in = $_POST['berufserf_'. $in .''];
    $in++;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: How is this `nr` generated? And why the empty space after concatenating `$nr`?

Comment: @BackinaFlash, with js.

Answer (score 0):

```
$time_.$in= ...
```

is not valid syntax. You're setting `$in = ...` and then concatenating `$time_` to it, in effect only changing `$in`. Use arrays instead:

```
$times = array();
$erfahrung = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $times[$i] = $_POST['zeit_' . $i];
    $erfahrung[$i] = $_POST['berufserf_'. $in];
}
```

Comment: thanks but ``$times_nr`` has also dynamic part: ``nr`` what about that?

Comment: @doniyor I don't see a `$times_nr` in your code. But you can access all the times with `$times[$nr]`.

Comment: didnot you see why i am doing this: ``$time_.$in``. this is the reason why i want ``times_1``,``times_2``,...etc

Comment: @doniyor That's not how it's done. Use an array instead — `$times[0]`, `$times[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
$time_.$in = 'something';
```

it will set $in to 'something' and then return concatenation of $time_ and 'something'

Proper syntax would be:

```
$varName = 'time_' . $in;
$$varName = 'something';
```

And of course it would be much neater to use array here.

Comment: are you sure with this? did you test it?

Comment: and by attaching to $_time I did not meant it will be modified. clarified answer.

Comment: and I am 100% sure this is why your loop is infinite. you are setting $in to $_POST['berufserf_X'] then incrementing it getting some unexpected results, and it never becomes grater than 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $in=1;
while($in<5){
    if(array_key_exist('zeit_'. $in, $_POST)){
    $time_.$in=$_POST['zeit_'. $in .''];
    $erfahrung_. $in = $_POST['berufserf_'. $in .''];
    $in++;
}
}
```